# Geocoding for many addresses

Tags: geocoding

why doesn't geocoding allow me to create markings for more than 11 addresses? I have hundreds of addresses in a database, but no Long Lat information. I need to mark all these addresses on a map. Somehow it displays only the first 11 markings. 
This question has been asked earlier i know and the solution is to set an interval between markers. I was able to display all by using a time interval between the markings. This solution is obviously too slow. Is there a better solution now?

Rgds

Comment: See a useful link from Geographic Information Systems: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15052/how-to-avoid-google-map-geocode-limit?newreg=3aae290343534fc58974545e4bcb1bc5

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear to me, but I understand that you are trying to show address locations on a map without knowing their coordinates. Using Google Maps, for example, you don't actually need latitude/longitude. But do you know the addresses are correct? Or, if you *aren't* using Google Maps but have a different use case entirely, then perhaps you do need the coordinates.

I work for [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com) where we perform both of these services (verifying addresses and geocoding them, meaning supplying lat/lon information).

Getting lat/lon can be tricky, especially considering that addresses are often so different and anything but "normalized" or standardized. Google and similar services approximate addresses but do not verify them, and their lat/lon is sometimes equally a best-guess.

Judging from your question, it seems like something like the [LiveAddress API](http://www.smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) would suit you well -- and it's free for low volume use. It's quite accurate, but in cases where it's "really" far off (meaning, a city block usually; still not too bad), it does return the level of resolution for each query.

If you have further questions or clarifications, feel free to respond (I'll help you out).

Answer (score 0):

Geocoding has some limitations on converting address into lat long. This is casued by OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.

Client side geocoding has some limitation of 20 queries per minute or sec. Server side geocoding also has limitations but after 2500 queries

I have worked on this issue and I used tips based on this solution via PHP/JavaScript and AJAX:

http://webstutorial.com/google-server-side-geocoding-php-infobox/website-tweaks/google#comment-429147758